# Populating part of a formula with the contents of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a simple formula in cell B1 it looks like:

=Robert!B$63

In column A I have a list of names. I wonder if it's possible to write a formula that can take the name from a cell in Column A *and fill in the formula with it* such that for example, "*=Robert!B$63*"  becomes "*=Mary!B$63*", simply by inputting Mary into column A?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the data you want together in B, like

=A$63&"!B$63"

which will give you the desired text (try that first, so the syntax is correct). If you then want that right away interpreted as a formula again, you can use indirect() around it:

=INDIRECT(A$63&"!B$63")

and it will go the the sheet "Mary" (or whatever you type in A$63), and fetch the value from B$63 there.